# Warn User Before leaving page with unsaved changes in page

Tags: jquery

how to stop the window.onbeforeunload event in jquery

when we do some changes in page and try to move out of page, how to handle that leave page or stay on this page popup

Comment: you can try using the event `$(window).on('beforeunload', function () { return "Are you sure you want to leave this page?" });`

Comment: Thank you but my question is like how to stop that event that event

Comment: but your question says **Warn User Before Leaving Page**?

Comment: sorry for that but that is what want

Comment: what exactly do you mean by stopping that event? every page has to unload.

Comment: instead of browser popup i want to show custom popup in that event

Comment: i don't think it is possible. you can just add a confirm alert

Comment: here's an SO link you can refer that says its not possible http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18510782/how-to-show-custom-pop-up-when-detect-browser-close-event